# Dynamic programming assigning tasks to different computers

Tags: algorithm, rust, dynamic-programming

I have the following dynamic programming problem that I just can't figure out.

Basically you have a table like this which represents the time it takes computer X to accomplish Y tasks (ordi means computer).

[image]

In this case, computer 1 will take 7 seconds to complete 1 task, 10 seconds to complete 2 tasks, etc.

Computer 2 will take 8 seconds to accomplish 1 task, 9 seconds to accomplish 2 tasks, etc.

Now, I want to write a dynamic programming algorithm that will tell me the minimum amount of time needed for Computer 1 AND 2 to accomplish 3 tasks, or the minimum time needed for Computer 1, 2 AND 3 to accomplish 5 tasks, etc.

**Keep in mind 2 constraints:** each computer involved **must** have at least 1 task assigned to it, and all 6 tasks **must** be distributed. For example, you couldn't use Computer 1 AND 2 to accomplish 1 task in the same way that you couldn't use 3 computers to accomplish less than 3 tasks (and each one must have a task).

This is the solution :
[image]

My (almost working) (Rust) code is below, it doesn't give the right numbers, though, can anyone get it to give the correct solution?

```
let costs = [
    [7, 10, 14, 20, 21, 30],
    [8, 9, 15, 10, 18, 20],
    [9, 9, 16, 28, 30, 40],
    [11, 15, 20, 30, 35, 20],
];

let mut optimal = vec![vec![999999999; costs[0].len()]; costs.len()];

for j in 0..costs[0].len() {
    optimal[0][j] = costs[0][j];
}

for i in 1..optimal.len() {
    for j in i..optimal[i].len() {
        let mut min = 999999999;

        for k in 0..j {
            let c = optimal[i - 1][j - k] + costs[i][k];
            min = std::cmp::min(c, min);
        }
        optimal[i][j] = min;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let costs = [
    [7, 10, 14, 20, 21, 30],
    [8, 9, 15, 10, 18, 20],
    [9, 9, 16, 28, 30, 40],
    [11, 15, 20, 30, 35, 20],
];

let mut optimal = vec![vec![999999999; costs[0].len()]; costs.len()];

for j in 0..costs[0].len() {
    optimal[0][j] = costs[0][j];
}

for i in 1..optimal.len() {
    for j in i..optimal[i].len() {
        let mut min = 999999999;

        //Wrong interval
        for k in 1..j+1 {
            //Index shift because we start with 0
            let c = optimal[i - 1][j - k] + costs[i][k-1];
            min = std::cmp::min(c, min);
        }
        optimal[i][j] = min;
    }
}
```

You essentially did not account that the column for 1 task is in column 0 and so on, so you will get 2 index shifts.